# Why Jpa not issuing JOIN query when using @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have two entities Program and Trending. This is the relationship between them.

In Trending:

```
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "Trending2Program", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = 
"FK_Trending_Program"))
private Program program;
```

In program:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "program")
private List<Trending> trendingList;
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface TrendingRepository extends JpaRepository <Trending, Integer> {
 List<Trending>findByDateBetween(LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate);
}
```

When executing findById from the service class then hibernate will create the necessary join:

```
 from
    Trending tre0_ 
 left outer join
    Program program1_ 
        on tre0_.trending2Program=program1_.Id
```

But when executing findByDateBetween hibernate will create two separate queries:

```
Hibernate: 
select
    ……
from
    Trending tre0_ 
where
    tre0_.Date between ? and ?

Hibernate: 
select
 …….
from
    Program program0_ 
where
    program0_.Id=?
```

What is different? What I am doing wrong and how can I config hibernate properly so it will create the necessary join when using findByDateBetween

Thank you

Comment: Did you see your `DB logs` internally? I say this because output logs of hibernate sometimes displays mistakes. Could you please confirm if you get the same result with `DB logs`?

Answer (score 0):

Well even though you declared `@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)` it got completely disabled once you put the fetching strategy as `FetchMode.JOIN`. With Join strategy Hibernate will try to always perform a join not giving heed to the fetch type. So the program will not be lazy loaded.

You should use `@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)` or just remove the `@Fetch` because `FetchMode.SELECT` is the default.

If you do this, as long as you don't do `trendingObj.getProgram()`, you should always get one select getting generated.

If you need program in one go then you probably need to go for eager fetch, i.e, keep `FetchMode.JOIN` and remove `fetch = FetchType.LAZY`. OR you could just write JPQL with the `@Query` annotation.

Comment: But what if I also need the program info? How can I "ask" hibernate to bring the data in one join?

Comment: Hi, updated the answer. Probably will work as you want now. Fingers crossed.

Comment: Removing LAZY will not work and I was hoping not to use JPQL. Thank you for suggestions.